# How to use index.php as a template for archives?

Tags: templates, archives

My archive pages are very much like my home page, except of course for the posts that are loaded. But design-wise, they're practically identical. So I would like to use index.php for both my homepage and my archive pages. How do I do that?

I know I could copy the code in `index.php`, paste it in `archive.php` and use

`/* Template Name: Archive */`

but I'd rather use one file so that if I need to change something, I can change it in one place only.

I also know (or at least, I think), if there's no `archive.php` Wordpress will automatically look for `index.php`, but the problem is I'm in a child theme, so it will go looking for the parent theme's `archive.php`, which is not okay because I do have and need an `archive.php` there.

So how can I explicitly tell Wordpress to look for `index.php` when an archive page is requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but in your archive.php file in the child theme use the following command to output the index.php file contents.

```
<?php
get_template_part( 'index' );
?>
```

This way you can have all the code in your index.php file but use it elsewhere preventing the duplication.

If you don't want to create an archive.php file then use this filter.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'archive_home_page_template', 99 );

function archive_home_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_archive() OR is_front_page() ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'index.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: Hey, your solution does work, but I was hoping for something even cleaner, like a function that told Wordpress to use index.php without having to create an archive.php file at all. But no one else chipped in, so I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Then try the 'template_include' filter, that should do what you require.  I've amended my answer.